# How to parse date time string with offset?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to parse this string:

```
string_date = "2020-10-06T12:31:15-05:00"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

But, it doesn't work. However, I am not sure how to properly put this into a datetime object. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your:

```
string_date = "2020-10-06T12:31:15-05:00"
```

seems like ISO format for me, so I did:

```
import datetime
string_date = "2020-10-06T12:31:15-05:00"
dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(string_date)
print(dt)
print(dt.tzinfo)
```

Output:

```
2020-10-06 12:31:15-05:00
UTC-05:00
```

Is above what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks. I didn't know about that function.